# How do you create a pivot table with a limited number of new columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have this dataframe for example:

| emp_id | label |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 101 |
| a1 | 102 |
| a1 | 103 |
| a1 | 104 |
| a2 | 420 |
| a2 | 17 |
| a3 | 99 |
| a3 | 100 |
| a3 | 101 |

And I want to create a new dataframe that is like a pivot table where the number of columns is fixed, and any row that would exceed that limit is dropped.

For example, if my column limit is 3, my desired output dataframe would be:

| emp_id | label_1 | label_2 | label_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 101 | 102 | 103 |
| a2 | 420 | 17 | NaN |
| a3 | 99 | 100 | 101 |

Where the 4th entry for `a1` is dropped, and the 3rd entry for `a2` is `NaN`.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar approach, we can use [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to enumerate `emp_id`, and use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to go to wide format, but filter groups based on the specified limit. Then use [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) to format the column headers:

```
# Set limit
limit = 3
# Create Groups
groups = df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount() + 1
# Pivot to wide format with new columns
df = df.pivot_table(index='emp_id',
                    columns=groups[groups.le(limit)],  #  Limit groups
                    values='label')
# Update Column Labels
df.columns = df.columns.map('label_{:.0f}'.format)
# Reset Index
df = df.reset_index()
```

`df`:

```
  emp_id  label_1  label_2  label_3
0     a1    101.0    102.0    103.0
1     a2    420.0     17.0      NaN
2     a3     99.0    100.0    101.0
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'emp_id': ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a3', 'a3', 'a3'],
    'label': [101, 102, 103, 104, 420, 17, 99, 100, 101]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby emp_id and use cumcount:

```
df['group'] = df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount().add(1)
```

Now you should have a new column with the names to use as pivot. You can keep only the labels you want and perform the pivot.

Something like:

```
df = df[df['group'].le(3)]
df.pivot(index='emp_id', columns='group', values='label')
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).add_prefix('label_')
df = df.reset_index()
```

*NB. I couldn't test the code*

Comment: There are some issues with this answer. You can't concat strings to ints without type casting. You're missing `()` after cumcount as it's a function `df['group'] = 'label_' + df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)`. Your pivot is missing an `index`. Also `.le('label_3')` is dangerous as this is lexicographic ordering an will not handle values like 10, 11 well, as alphabetically the order would be label_1, label_10, label_11, label_2, label_3, label_4. Which I assume is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone with limited connection, I tried to provide a minimal answer to help OP. Feel free to update my post if you like.

Comment: @Henry Hopefully fixed most of it, nightmare to type code on a phone!